# Best way to feed Data into Multiprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have some ambiguity in me. I'm novice. I have reads that Multiprocessing are making local copies of Global Variable on each Process. However, this only applies on Windows, since it creates new instance of Python. Meanwhile, in Linux, Child Process are forked into Parent.

Now, I have Global Variable that contains states of User-Choices. Taking a similar approach to switch statement using `dictionary` in Python.

```
case = { 'lead_type': 0, 'deep': 0 }
```

All this time, I store them first in `multiprocessing.Manager()` with the idea: it will help to avoid local copy inside each Process. But, `Manager()` create a new Proxy to share the data across Processes, which considered slow. Thus, `multiprocessing.Value()` is faster because it creates a pointer for that `case` object.

Knowing all of that, should I stick with the use of `Manager()` or `global`? Or can I put `dictionary` object into `Value()` somehow? Is using `Value()` considered a good practice?

**EDIT**:

```
import re
import csv
import json
import socket
import multiprocessing
from collections import defaultdict
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process, cpu_count, Queue

#This is the Target Dictionary
case = { 'lead_type': 0, 'file_type': 0, 'deep': 0 }

def websocket_tls(proc, cases):
    ...

def consumer(procs, cases):
    while True:
        proc = procs.get()
        if proc is None:
            break
        if cases['lead_type'] == 1:
            if cases['deep'] == 1:
                websocket_tls(proc, cases)
            elif cases['deep'] == 2:
                websocket_insecure(proc, cases)
            elif cases['deep'] == 3:
                gorilla_tls(proc, cases)
            else:
                gorilla(proc, cases)
        else:
            break

def producer(procs, cases):
    plist = []
    for i in range(cpu_count()):
        procs.put(None)
        p = Process(target = consumer, args = (procs, cases))
        p.start()
        total.append(p)
    for p in plist:
        p.join()

# Another function also use Case
def processor(file):
    procs = Queue(cpu_count()*10)
    if case['deep'] == 0:
        with open('payloads.json') as f:
            payloads = json.loads(f)

    #This is my ambiguity.
    #Should I keep case global or readded it to Manager to avoid copies? :
    cases = Manager().dict()
    for i, v in case.items():
        cases[i] = v
    cases['payload'] = payloads

    columns = defaultdict(list)
    if case['file_type'] == 0:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                liner = [line] + list(islice(f, cpu_count()))
                for i in liner:
                    procs.put(i.strip())
                producer(procs, cases)
    elif case['file_type'] == 1:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for rows in reader:
                for (i,v) in enumerate(row):
                    columns[i].append(v)
                procs.put(columns[9] + columns[3])
                producer(procs, cases)
    else:
        f = requests.get(file).text
        f = re.findall('(.*?),', f)
        for line in f:
            liner = [line] + list(islice(f, cpu_count()))
            for i in liner:
                procs.put(i.strip())
            producer(procs, cases)
    print('Result: ' + str(cases['Result']))
    print('Scrape: ' + str(cases['Scrape']))
    return

# Craft case identifying the correct file_type
def choose_file():
    print('1. Use .txt file')
    print('2. Use .csv file')
    print('3. Use Online Repository')
    answer = input('Choose: ')
    print()
    if answer == '1':
        case['file_type'] = 0
    elif answer == '2':
        case['file_type'] = 1
    else:
        case['file_type'] = 2
    file = input('Choose Location: ')
    return file

# Craft case to appropiate function with it's own deep
def menu():
    print('1) Test Alive Subdomain')
    print('2) Test Alive Proxy')
    print('3) Test Alive SNI')
    answer = input('Choose: ')
    print('')
    if asnwer == '1':
        print('1) Websocket Secure')
        print('2) Websocket Insecure')
        print('3) Websocket Secure with Gorilla')
        print('4) Websocket Insecure with Gorilla')
        answer = input('Choose: ')
        print('')
        if asnwer == '1':
            case['lead_type'] = 0
            case['deep'] = 0
        elif answer == '2':
            case['lead_type'] = 1
            case['deep'] = 0
        elif asnwer == '3':
            case['lead_type'] = 0
            case['deep'] = 1
        else:
            case['lead_type'] = 1
            case['deep'] = 1
    file = choose_file()
    processor(file)
    exit()
menu()
```

Added example to make it more clear @Booboo. As you can see, there's many function that accesses and modify the `case`, there's more actually. So, I can't make the `case` local, it stay `global`. The problem remains, should it keep `global` or need to be passed to `Manager().dict()` or even `multiprocessing.Value()` to avoid copies of `case`.

Also, good to mention that the `case` has more suplement into it such as `payloads` on `processor()`. Note that there's more data to feed, it can be more bigger, depends on the user choices in `menu()`. After data feeding is completed, it's time for `multiprocessing` to determine result.

**Analogy**:

Most Functions -> Modify / Craft `case` -> Final `case` -> `Manager().dict()` / Stay `global` / `multiprocessing.Value` -> Producer & Consumer. `case` stays on Read-Only.

Comment: If you post a simplified and [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) perhaps I could show you a solution. But right now it's not clear to me how you even use `case`. How does each process update it? And, no, you cannot put a dictionary in a `multiprocessing.Value` (at least I can't). As of now there are not enough details to provide a decent answer. But if `case` is read only, just create it at global scope; this is not a problem.

Comment: Added examples @Booboo

Comment: I don't think this application should be multiprocessed or have any form of parallelization, as you really must be 100% sure no data races happen or deadlocks and all data stays synchronized you are introducing too much places where this may be a problem to maintain, you are eventually going to run into a situation where you need a handmade GIL to stop all these problems, which will eventually limit your hypothetical multiprocess speedup.

Comment: The example were only intended for '_minimal, reproducible example_', the intention of parallelization is because I'm shooting 10-mil wordlist against a single domain ( subdomain bruteforce ). As for '_eventually limit your hypothetical multiprocess speedup_' its true. Eventually with all of data introduced, the canonical of being fast wouldn't matter anymore but atleast the general intention is no too stress memory by not feeding unnecessary copies of data that can just be accessed via a single pointer. @AhmedAEK

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with your minimal example, and to be honest you are using the wrong tools which will require you over 30 times more resources than actually needed to hit that mark, you should be using a faster language like rust, with a "lockless queue" if you want to hit that, as python is over 30 times slower in sockets handling.

Comment: Thank you again, I will consider your suggested option. Might moving to `go`-lang as secondary but for now, my thread stands on `python` side @AhmedAEK

Comment: You have quite a few issues with your updated code. Just to point out a few: (1) You have `Queue(cpu_count*10)`, but that should be `Queue(cpu_count() * 10)`. But why put a size limit on it at all? (2) You join all the processes so at that point you know they are no longer running, yet you then call `p.terminate()` on an already terminated process -- and this is only being called for the last process. It does not make sense. (3) You need to use more meaningful names for your objects. `procs` for a queue? `total` for a list of `Process` instances? By the way, `total` is not defined.

Comment: Sorry, that was a rough rewrite from my main script @Booboo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Based on your updated code/description where the dictionary has no keys added or deleted but integer values of existing keys might be changed by a process and the change reflected to other processes using the dictionary, then there are two approaches:

1. Use a managed dictionary (e.g. `multiprocessing.Manager().dict()`). As you have noted, accessing or modifying key values are somewhat expensive since it results in making a remote method call to the actual dictionary that resides in a process created by the `SyncManager` instance. But multiprocessing is only advantageous if your worker function(s) are sufficiently CPU-intensive such that what is gained by running these functions in parallel more than offsets what is lost due to the additional overhead incurred by multiprocessing (e.e. process creation and inter-process communication). So you need to ask how much of your total processing is represented by the accessing of the dictionary values. If it is a significant portion then this is not the best approach but perhaps also your processes are not sufficiently CPU-intensive to warrant a multiprocessing approach.
2. Use `multiprocessing.Value` instances as the values for the dictionary. Each process will have its own copy of the dictionary but the values stored are sharable because they reside in shared memory. These instances can be created with or without a lock. Updates under control of a lock to force updates to be "one-at-a-time" would be required if the updating logic is not atomic. For example, if you decide that a new value for key 'x' needs to be replaced and this new value is not based on the value of something that is being shared (which might get updated while you are executing your update logic), then you just need a statement such as `d['x'].value = new_value`. However, an update such as `d[x].value += 1` needs to be done under control of a lock: `with d['x'].get_lock(): d['x'].value += 1`.

In the code below, which is a modified version of my third coding example that I originally posted (since this version is closes to the approach you are taking, i.e. using `multiprocessing.Process` instances with a `multiprocssing.Queue`), I am following the second approach outlined above and using a regular dictionary with `multiprocessing.Value` instances as the values. I have added code just to show how an update made by one process is visible to the other processes. Normally, the way I am updating a value, i.e. first reading the current value and then replacing the value with a new value computed from the current value, would require that these operations be done under control of a lock to ensure that no other process can be modifying this key's value while this non-atomic logic is being performed. I am, however, not doing this under control of a lock just because I don't believe that the way you are updating values requires a lock and I didn't want to imply otherwise.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count, Queue, Value, current_process

def user_choices():
    props = {'deep': Value('i', 0, lock=False)}
    lead_type = input('Put Leader type: ')
    props['lead_type'] = Value('i', int(lead_type), lock=False)
    return props

def processing():
    props = user_choices()
    processors = [ 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah' ]
    queue = Queue()
    n_processors = cpu_count()
    for p in processors:
        queue.put(p)
    for _ in range(n_processors):
        # Use None as the sentinel so it cannot be mistaken for actual data:
        queue.put(None)

    procs = [Process(target=processes, args=(queue, props)) for _ in range(n_processors)]
    for p in procs:
        p.start()
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

def processes(queue, props):
    import time

    while True:
        process = queue.get()
        if process is None: # Sentinel
            break
        v = props['lead_type']
        if v.value == 1:
            new_value = 2
        else:
            new_value = 1
        v.value = new_value
        print(f"Process {current_process().pid} is setting props['lead_type'] to {new_value}: {process}")
        time.sleep(.1) # Give other processes a chance to rum

# For platforms that use *spawn*, such as windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    processing()
```

Prints:

```None
Put Leader type: 1
Process 8764 is setting props['lead_type'] to 2: blah
Process 23740 is setting props['lead_type'] to 1: blah
Process 15276 is setting props['lead_type'] to 2: blah
Process 8984 is setting props['lead_type'] to 1: blah
Process 18300 is setting props['lead_type'] to 2: blah
Process 10740 is setting props['lead_type'] to 1: blah
Process 17796 is setting props['lead_type'] to 2: blah
Process 7880 is setting props['lead_type'] to 1: blah
```

---

**Original Posting**

A few observations:

1. Your current code will result in all of your children processes except for one never terminating: You need to put N instances of 'ends' to the queue where N is the number of child processes you are creating so that each process knows that there is no more data. Right now you have only put a single instance of 'ends' on the queue so only one child process can get it and the others will wait indefinitely doing a blocking `get` against an empty queue.
2. You can greatly simplify the code and use a standard dictionary by using a multiprocessing pool, e.g. a `militprocessing.Pool`. The idea is to have the main process initialize the `props` dictionary and then initialize within each pool process' address space a global variable `pool` initialized appropriately. Alternatively, you could pass the `props` dictionary as an an argument to `processes`. Of course, in your current code you could have also passed it as additional argument.
3. Multiprocessing will perform worse unless function `processes` is sufficiently CPU-intensive.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def init_pool_processes(the_props):
    """
    Initialize global variable props for each pool process.
    """
    global props

    props = the_props

def user_choices():
    props = {'deep': 0}
    lead_type = input('Put Leader type: ')
    props['lead_type'] = int(lead_type)
    return props

def processing():
    props = user_choices()
    processors = [ 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah' ]

    with Pool(initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(props,)) as pool:
        pool.map(processes, processors)

def processes(process):
    print(f"Lead {props['lead_type']}: {process}")

# For platforms that use *spawn*, such as windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    processing()
```

If you want to use individual `multiprocessing.Process` instances then a simpler approach would be to use a `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue` with *daemon* child processes.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count, JoinableQueue

def user_choices():
    props = {'deep': 0}
    lead_type = input('Put Leader type: ')
    props['lead_type'] = int(lead_type)
    return props

def processing():
    props = user_choices()
    processors = [ 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah' ]
    queue = JoinableQueue()
    for p in processors:
        queue.put(p)

    for _ in range(cpu_count()):
        # A daemon process will terminate automatically when the main
        # process terminates:
        Process(target=processes, args=(queue, props), daemon=True).start()

    # Wait for all queue items to have been processed:
    queue.join()

def processes(queue, props):
    while True:
        process = queue.get()
        print(f"Lead {props['lead_type']}: {process}")
        queue.task_done() # Show we have finished processing the item

# For platforms that use *spawn*, such as windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    processing()
```

If you use a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance, then you need to put N *sentinel* items (where N is the number of child processes) on the queue that signify there is no more data to be gotten from the queue. I think that using `None` is a better choice of a sentinel value than 'ends' as it could not possibly be mistaken for actual data:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count, Queue

def user_choices():
    props = {'deep': 0}
    lead_type = input('Put Leader type: ')
    props['lead_type'] = int(lead_type)
    return props

def processing():
    props = user_choices()
    processors = [ 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah' ]
    queue = Queue()
    n_processors = cpu_count()
    for p in processors:
        queue.put(p)
    for _ in range(n_processors):
        # Use None as the sentinel so it cannot be mistaken for actual data:
        queue.put(None)

    procs = [Process(target=processes, args=(queue, props)) for _ in range(n_processors)]
    for p in procs:
        p.start()
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

def processes(queue, props):
    while True:
        process = queue.get()
        if process is None: # Sentinel
            break
        print(f"Lead {props['lead_type']}: {process}")

# For platforms that use *spawn*, such as windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    processing()
```

All three code examples above result in the following output:

```None
Put Leader type: 1
Lead 1: blah
Lead 1: blah
Lead 1: blah
Lead 1: blah
Lead 1: blah
Lead 1: blah
Lead 1: blah
Lead 1: blah
```

Comment: Hi @Booboo, thank you for the breakdown. From example, it use `props` as `local`, then passed into `processing()`. The reason I put it in Global is because there's many function that crafts the `dictionary`, so I can't really make it local since it would be passed anywhere. Now, should I keep it `global` or passed it again into `Manager()`? It's also because the `dictionary` could be even bigger as it's also contains `payloads` for `socket` requests.

Comment: This is why it is important to post code that demonstrates how exactly you are using things per the comment I posted on your question. But you did not do that and I have spent too much time posting something that is of little value to you. I don't understand what you mean when you say "there's many function that crafts the dictionary." When and how? If it is your processes that need to update the dictionary by adding new keys and it must be sharable across processes, then it needs to be a managed dictionary. I can't read minds: **Update your code (minimally) with what you are actually doing.**

Comment: Your post is useful, it's exactly mention the problem in my Multiprocessing part. The example on my thread is exactly how I implement Multiprocessing and you mention the problem with it, I don't see anything that has '_a little value_' from your post. I simply re-asking because I got confused how can I place my `dictionary`, wether it's should stay as `global` variable or re-added it into `Manager().dict()`. I think that's the general Idea of my thread. I will update the script to a long one.

Comment: These answers are great to read.

Comment: Question: Now that you have updated code I don't see any instances of your child processes adding additional keys to the dictionary, i.e. they are only updating the value of existing keys. But I don't want to assume anything, so is this true?

Comment: True. It's Read-Only. @Booboo

Comment: I have posted an update. I am sorry: it's a bit verbose.